# How to draw a Cartesian plane with shaded upper half plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, graphs

I am a beginner at LaTeX. Could someone please guide me how can I draw the attached picture with caption in my LaTeX presentation?

P.S. I want the area with diagonal lines to be a shaded area (preferably in grey).
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? :)

Comment: For PDF patterns, see pages 730-737 of the tikz manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

This is pretty simple in `tikz` using the `\draw` and `\fill` commands for lines (`--`) and rectangles (`rectangle`), as well as a couple of nodes for labels and a `figure` environment for the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}  % needed for \mathbb

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[lightgray] (0, 0) rectangle (6, 3);
            \draw (0, 0) -- (6, 0);
            \draw (3, -1) -- (3, 3);
            \node[below right] at (3, 0) {0};
            \node[above right] at (6, 3) {\(\mathbb{C}\)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Upper half plane}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Willoughby. I was able to get the figure using these commands.

Answer (score 6):

A solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture*}(-4.5,-1.5)(5,5)
\psframe*[linecolor=Gainsboro!50!Lavender](-4.5,0)(4.5,4.5)
\psaxes[linewidth=1pt, labels=none,ticks=none]{-}(0,0)(-4.5,-1.5)(4.5,4.5)
\uput[dr](0,0){$O$}\uput[ur](4.5,4.5){$\mathbb{C}$}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[white!50!gray] (-4,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw (-4.25,0)--(4.25,0);
    \draw (0,-.25)--(0,4.25);
    \node[below right] at (0,0) {$0$};
    \node[right] at (4,4) {$\mathbb C$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It will give you this:

[image]